# select count from union of two tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, count, max, union

I have a union among two tables in SQL Server. Every select among unioned tables contains a count.
I'd want to collect results so that every unioned record contains both counters.
My query is something similar to the following:

```
SELECT ID,
       NAME,
       MAX(tableAcounter) AS counterA,
       MAX(tableBcounter) AS counterB
FROM ((SELECT ID,
              NAME,
              COUNT(*) OVER() AS tableAcounter
              0 AS tableBcounter
       FROM tableA
       GROUP BY ID,
                NAME)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT ID,
             NAME,
             0 AS tableAcounter,
             COUNT(*) OVER() AS tableBCounter
      FROM tableB
      GROUP BY ID,
               NAME))
GROUP BY ID,
         NAME
```

Let's say that I have 3 record on table A anche 5 records on table B.
I don't understand why I obtain records like:

```
ID: 1
NAME: foo
counterA: 3
counterB: 0

ID: 5
NAME: baz
counterA: 0
counterB: 5

ID 21
NAME: bar
counterA: 3
counterB: 0
```

instead of:

```
ID: 1
NAME: foo
counterA: 3
counterB: 5

ID: 5
NAME: baz
counterA: 3
counterB: 5

ID 21
NAME: bar
counterA: 3
counterB: 5
```

Comment: You have three different `ID`s and you group by that `ID`, why should this return less than three rows?

Comment: I'm editing to make my question clearer.
In any case I'd want every row with both counterA and counterB other than 0